# React State Improvement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

Can we write the code in a shorter version?

For example:

```
function Account() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState('')
  
  return <input onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)} />
}
```

Could we do it even more shorter like without creating new function? Like:

```
<input onChange={setCode} />
```

Some way?

Best!

Comment: did you try the solution you propose?

Comment: The problem with `onChange` is that it passes on the `event` instead of the value, so you have to extract the `event.target.value` before you can pass it on to `setCode` (unless, you want an event in your `code` variable). I sometimes create a little helper `const withTargetValue = fn => event => fn(event.target.value)` and use it this way:
`<input onChange={withTargetValue(setCode)} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom `useEventState` helper that wraps React's `useState` and adds an additional setter to the tuple (array) it returns:

```js
const useEventState = value => {
  const [ initialValue, directSetter ] = useState(value);
  
  return [
    initialValue,
    directSetter,
    e => directSetter(e.target.value)
  ];
}
```

I think it makes sense to also still return the original setter that takes a value directly. If you only set `code` through an `onChange` event, you could even replace it with the `e.target.value` one.

Here's a quick example (in which I added a button that uses the direct setter to show that's still useful to include):

```js
function Account() {
  const [code, setCode, setCodeFromEvent] = useEventState('');
    
  const toUpper = () => {
    setCode(code.toUpperCase());
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={code} onChange={setCodeFromEvent} />
      <p>Your code: {code}</p>
      <button onClick={toUpper}>To upper case</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Account />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script>
const { useState } = React;
const useEventState = value => {
  const [ initialValue, directSetter ] = useState(value);
  
  return [
    initialValue,
    directSetter,
    e => directSetter(e.target.value)
  ];
}
</script>
```